# put/get HashMap complexity in java 8 jdk

Tags: java, data-structures

as far as i know the worst case scenario of put/get operation in HashMap implemented in java is o(n).

while researching for an efficient data structure for a project i'm working on i've seen a comment here from a guy which says that in java 8 JDK the HashMap complexity for those operations are O(logn) but i couldn't find documentation about it.
is that true, so i can rely on it?

if that's really the truth , how does it implemented?
my guess is that each "cell" in the HashMap is implemented as a balanced tree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's correct.  As of Java 8, if a single hash bucket contains 8 or more objects, then the linked list at that location is converted to a tree (red-black balanced tree).

There's an article on it [here](https://dzone.com/articles/hashmap-performance).  The OpenJDK JEP is [here](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/180).

Interestingly though.... this `O(logn)` relies on the objects having implemented `comparable`.  So technically, you're correct, as long as you only put `comparable` objects in your map.  If you don't, then it's back to plain old linked list and `O(n)`.